# grails g:each tag is not showing anything in view

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am using grails 2.4.2. I need to show some value in view from a list. That's why I am using g:each but nothing is shown to view although it's working fine in controller. I never saw this issue before. Can anybody please help me on this please ?!!! Here are my attempts below :::

in my controller ##

```
def homePage() {
    def androidGameInstance = AndroidGameDist.listOrderByDownloadCount(order: 'desc',max: 10)
    androidGameInstance.each {
        println(it.downloadCount)
    }
    [androidGameInstance: androidGameInstance]
}
```

in my view ##

```
<body>
<g:each in="${androidGameInstance}" status="i" var="androidGameInstance">
    <p>value : ${androidGameInstance.downloadCount}</p>
</g:each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

Controller:

```
def homePage() {
    def androidGameInstanceList = AndroidGameDist.listOrderByDownloadCount(order: 'desc',max: 10)
    androidGameInstanceList.each {
        println(it.downloadCount)
    }
    [androidGameInstanceList: androidGameInstanceList]
}
```

gsp:

```
<g:each in="${androidGameInstanceList}" status="i" var="androidGameInstance">
    <p>value : ${androidGameInstance.downloadCount}</p>
</g:each>
```

Comment: what was the big deal with just a 'list' word ?!!!!!!!!  - can you please explain ???

Comment: when you do <g:each in="${androidGameInstanceList}" status="i" var="androidGameInstance"> you are creating a var called androidGameInstance each time you iterate the list, so in the first iteration you where overriding the original androidGameInstance (list) with the first value of it.